# Login form doesn't disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm doing a webpage for a school work and I'm trying to do a button that, when you click it, pops out and then when you click it again it pops in. The button that holds the login button should hide the whole form until I hover over it and then click login ("logga" in Swedish)...

But the form shows the whole time...

Some of the code is in Swedish, but it should not matter anyway..

HTML5:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loggaIn.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet_spelnord.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="knapp.css">
  <script src="loggain.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Spelnörd</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <header id="top_bg">
                    <h1 id="titel"> Spelnörd</h1>           
                </header>
<div class='hexagon'>
  <ul>
    <li class='polygon_top' id="toggle-login">
      <a href="#">Logga in
      <div id="login">
  <div id="triangle"></div>
  <h1>Log in</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
  </form>
</div></a>      
    </li>
    <li class='polygon_top'></li>
    <li class='polygon_top'>
      <a href="#">Dribbble</a>
    </li>
    <li class='polygon_bottom'>
      <a href="#">Forrst</a>
    </li>
    <li class='polygon_bottom'></li>
    <li class='polygon_bottom'>
      <a href="#">Twitter</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS for the button:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/*=================================== container 
*/

.hexagon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24.5%;
  left: 15%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 60px;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.00005); 
}

/*=================================== top and bottom triangle
*/

.polygon_top,
.polygon_bottom {
  border-left: 18px solid transparent;
  border-right: 18px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out, border 0.1s linear, border-radius 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.polygon_top a,
.polygon_bottom a {
  color: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0);
  display: block;
  font-size: 0em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  transition: color, font-size 0.3s;
}

.polygon_top:nth-child(1),
.polygon_top:nth-child(3),
.polygon_bottom:nth-child(4),
.polygon_bottom:nth-child(6) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.polygon_top:nth-child(1):hover > a,
.polygon_top:nth-child(3):hover > a,
.polygon_bottom:nth-child(4):hover > a,
.polygon_bottom:nth-child(6):hover > a {
  color: #373737;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.polygon_top:nth-child(1) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #E56717;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(-30px) translateY(-15px);
}

.polygon_top:nth-child(1):hover {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-left: 18px solid #E56717;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.polygon_top:nth-child(1) > a {
  line-height: 30px;
}

.polygon_top:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #E56717;
  transform: translateX(12px) translateY(15px);
}

.polygon_top:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #E56717;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(30px) translateY(-15px);
}

.polygon_top:nth-child(3):hover {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-right: 18px solid #E56717;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.polygon_top:nth-child(3) > a {
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.polygon_bottom:nth-child(4) {
  border-top: 30px solid #565051;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(-30px) translateY(15px);
}

.polygon_bottom:nth-child(4):hover {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-left: 18px solid #565051;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.polygon_bottom:nth-child(4) > a {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.polygon_bottom:nth-child(5) {
  border-top: 30px solid #565051;
  transform: translateX(12px) translateY(-15px);
}

.polygon_bottom:nth-child(6) {
  border-top: 30px solid #565051;
  transform: translateX(30px) translateY(15px);
}

.polygon_bottom:nth-child(6):hover {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-right: 18px solid #565051;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.polygon_bottom:nth-child(6) > a {
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

CSS for the form:

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);

  #login{
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:8px;
  margin-bottom:2%;
  transition:opacity 1s;
  -webkit-transition:opacity 1s;
}

#triangle{
  width:0;
  border-top:12x solid transparent;
  border-right:12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:12px solid #3399cc;
  border-left:12px solid transparent;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#login h1{
  background:#3399cc;
  padding:20px 0;
  font-size:140%;
  font-weight:300;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
}

form{
  background:#f0f0f0;
  padding:6% 4%;
}

input[type="email"],input[type="password"]{
  width:92%;
  background:#fff;
  margin-bottom:4%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:4%;
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-size:95%;
  color:#555;
}

input[type="submit"]{
  width:100%;
  background:#3399cc;
  border:0;
  padding:4%;
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-size:100%;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:background .3s;
  -webkit-transition:background .3s;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover{
  background:#2288bb;
}
```

Javascript for the klick function:

```
$('#toggle-login').click(function(){
  $('#login').toggle();
});
```

Comment: You havn't included jquery in your page, neither are you waiting for document ready. check out the jQuery webpage.

Comment: you need to add jquery file in your page.it is working.<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I now have the document ready and link to ajax, but it still dont work... ghaaa :)

Comment: I dont think there's any issue with the code. It's working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4L193dr/

Comment: how can i get theform to hide automatically when the button goes back in the hexagon

Answer (score 0):

Try include jquery and then your javascript code, and do it to the end of your body tag...

```
    <body>
    ....
    some html here ....
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#toggle-login').click(function(){
                $('#login').toggle();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thx this work!
Ecxept that the form shows the whole time until i klick the login button it hides. I must hide it somehow when the the page loads..

Comment: you can use css to hide it. #login{display:none;}

Comment: Can i ask just one more question to u? 
Im trying to get the form to hide automatically when the button goes back in the hexagon...

Comment: use a on ended transition event: ex element.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', 
    transitionListener, false );

Comment: but if you hide it when the button goes back in, you couldnt use your form, Just try, you will realize.

Comment: hmm have tried some, but the it just messes up the code.. mabey thats not so bad if the form i visible even after its just a little bit anoying.. :)